# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in JavaScript - Quiz

Tags: javascript

I need help. I wrote this JS code and when I want to see in the browser it shows only the created button with ID "submit". In console of the browser was written Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier and kviz.js:38. I know I dont have a results part, but it doesn't matter now, it has to show me a question I think.  Any solutions?

```
function postavKviz(){
const output = [];
otazky.forEach(
    (momentalniOtazka, cisloOtazky) => {

        const odpovedi = [];
        for (letter in momentalniOtazka.odpovedi){
            odpovedi.push(
                `<label>
                <input type="radio" name="otazka${cisloOtazky}" value="${letter}">
                ${letter} :
                ${momentalniOtazka.odpovedi[letter]}
                </label>`
                );

        }
        output.push(
            `<div class="otazka"> ${momentalniOtazka.otazka} </div>
            <div class="odpovedi"> ${odpovedi.join('')} </div>`
            );
        }
    );
    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
}
function ukazVysledky(){

}
    const quizContainer = document.getElementById("kviz");
    const resultsContainer = document.getElementById("answers");
    const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit")
    const otazky = [
{
    otazka: "Na jaké mocnosti se Československo po 1. světové válce orientovalo?",
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Sovětský Svaz, Čína"
        b: "Velká Británie, Francie, USA"
        c: "Německo, Itálie"
    },
    spravnaOdpoved: "b"
},
{
    otazka: "Jaké stopy po společném soužití s Československem má Podkarpatská Rus?",
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Infrastruktura"
        b: "Jazyk"
        c: "Pamatáky odkazující na Československo"
    },
    spravnaOdpoved: "a"
},
{
    otazka: "Jaké státy tvořily Malou dohodu?",
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Velká Británie, Francie, Německo"
        b: "Československo, Jugoslávie, Rumunsko"
        c: "USA, Čína, Japonsko"
    },
    spravnaOdpoved: "b"
},
{
    otazka: "Na jaké mocnosti se Československo po 1. světové válce orientovalo?",
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Sovetský Svaz, Čína"
        b: "Velká Británie, Francie, USA"
        c: "Německo, Itálie"
    },
    spravnaOdpoved: "b"
},
{
    otazka: "Jaké komory tvořily za dob první republiky parlament?",
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Rada státu, národní zasedání dělnické třídy"
        b: "Senát, rada státu"
        c: "Poslanecká sněmovna, senát"
    },
    spravnaOdpoved: "c"
},
{
    otazka: "K čemu sloužilo v dobách prvni republiky Rudolfínum?",
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Zasadala zde rada státu"
        b: "Zasedal zde senát"
        c: "Zasedala zde poslanecká sněmovna"
    },
    spravnaOdpoved: "c"
},
{
    otazka: "Díku čemu přežil atentát Karel Kramař?",
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Střelec ho minul"
        b: "Střelec ho trefil do místa, kde byl chráněn trojím krytím"
        c: "Střelec ho zasáhnul do nohy, ale nebylo to život ohrozující"
    },
    spravnaOdpoved: "b"
},
{
    otazka: "Díky čemu je firma Tomáše Baťy tak úspěšná?",
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Obuv v té době nikdo jiný nevyráběl"
        b: "Měl mnoho kamarádů, herců, kteří jeho firmu výrazně propagovali"
        c: "Získal velké zkušenosti ve Spojených státech"
    },
    spravnaOdpoved: "c"
},
{
    otazka: 'Proč se Osvobozené divadlo nazývá "Osvobozené"?',
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Protože se divadlo snaží odpoutat od stereotypu, které v té době v divadlech bylo"
        b: "Protože tam hráli vojáci, kteří bojovali v 1. světové válce"
        c: "Nemá to žádný pádný důvod, slovo osvobozené bylo nejoblíbenější slovo zakladatele Jana Wericha"
    },
    spravnaOdpoved: "a"
},
{
    otazka: "Jací bratři stáli za vznikem Barrandova?",
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Miloš a Václav Havel"
        b: "Karel a Josef Čapek"
        c: "Tomáš Garrigue a Ludvík Masaryk"
    }
    spravnaOdpoved: "a";
}
];

postavKviz();
submitButton.addEventListener('click', ukazVysledky);
```

Comment: Objects require commas after each property key/value pair. I'd recommend using an editor that can show simple syntax errors like this. Unrelated, but you also have a spurious `;` in the last question. Also unrelated, but it's easier to develop in small, digestible chunks, so errors are caught earlier in the process.

Comment: use code editor, like vs code. it will find this type of issues

Comment: missing comm in object properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the "," behind the answers. See for example here, I added them after the a,b,c. You will have to do this for the other answers too.

```
    otazka: "Jaké stopy po společném soužití s Československem má Podkarpatská Rus?",
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Infrastruktura",
        b: "Jazyk",
        c: "Pamatáky odkazující na Československo",
    },
    spravnaOdpoved: "a"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I correct a "," behind a and b. But i should place it after c? And one more thing. The problem was moved into row 130, with "spravnaOdpoved: "a"". Any solutions? :D

Comment: @Destralux As stated in my original comment and elsewhere, you have a spurious semicolon there. Whether you put a trailing comma in your objects is a style choice. You'd be better off with a JS tutorial or class rather than asking basic syntax questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You must separate object properties with a comma between(and also don't use semicolons as a separator)

for example:

```
{
    otazka: "Jací bratři stáli za vznikem Barrandova?",
    odpovedi:
    {
        a: "Miloš a Václav Havel",
        b: "Karel a Josef Čapek",
        c: "Tomáš Garrigue a Ludvík Masaryk"
    },
    spravnaOdpoved: "a"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But now i have problem on the end of code (row 130),   "spravnaOdpoved: "a"". Any solutions? :D

Comment: @Destralux You have placed a semicolon on line 130, it should be after array closing bracket, not in one of its elements and in an object.

Comment: I think it's better you go find it with the help of an editor :)